# Is there software that displays text on top of windows?

Tags: windows-7, script, software-rec, always-on-top

Is there software or a script which lets me display text on a Windows 7 screen all the time, always on top of other windows?

Comment: Sounds like a good recipe for [screen burn-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in) if you ask me.  We could help you much better if you indicate *what* you want to do this for, and *why*.  (if you know programming, you could do something like FRAPS, and hook into the desktop window manager's draw routines)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into both. Here is what i am trying to do. I have autohotkey script, I wrote which read user input like number if user presses 22 it will open like stream in VLC Player and it will automatically full-screen that stream, but at same time, I want to display text like on TV's it displays channel number. `22` if user presses 23 it will open another stream which might be open in Internet explorer and it will full-screen that, so for that I want it to display `23` always on top. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to find something that will display text in the taskbar since that is already being displayed all the time.

I used to do this with a utility called [TClockEx](http://www.rcis.co.za/dale/tclockex/) but it is quite old, I don't know if it will work under Windows 7. You can drive this with an AHK script if you need to.